# What is the difference between Date.addingTimeInterval(_:) and Date.advanced(by:)?

Tags: swift, foundation

Foundation's `Date` struct provides both `Date.addingTimeInterval(_:)` and `Date.advanced(by:)` which appear to be functionally identical, but are obviously separate methods. Is there actually a difference between them or are they ultimately the same?

Looking at the documentation, `advanced(by:)` is missing anything at all, and `addingTimeInterval(_:)` only says

> The value to add, in seconds.

When comparing to NSDate, `advanced(by:)` is missing entirely. The plot thickens!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.addingTimeInterval(_:)` is a long-existing method, coming from ObjC NSDate. `.advanced(by:)` exists to match Strideable conformance in Swift. Date similarly has a Stride typealias.

That said, Date does not actually conform to Strideable, [and this has been discussed and generally rejected](https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-make-foundation-date-conform-to-strideable/8100).

The Strideable pseudo-conformance seems to have been added as part of [a large merge from Xcode 11.4](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/e7cd5ab17f5ce92315f0e23b269628ac2b9369ea#diff-71f99fa9926eed91158761067da20dea1b084c9ef4dbfcd546f9dc3a5520b807) in an extension called `Schedulers+Date` that appears to be part of Combine (which is not open source). I don't see any discussion of it in the forums, [except for a note that it broke existing code](https://forums.swift.org/t/foundation-date-conforming-to-strideable-ios-13/33221). The change notes:

```
// Date cannot conform to Strideable per rdar://35158274
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
 extension Date /* : Strideable */ {
```

My hunch is that somewhere inside of Combine, there's a retroactive conformance of Date to Strideable. You can get the same by just asking for it:

```
extension Date: Strideable {}
```

It feels like the Swift stdlib team accepted that Date should not be Strideable (and I agree with the reasoning, because it invites a lot of common date bugs), but some other team in Apple wanted it and put the hooks into stdlib anyway, without putting in the conformance.

Comment: IIRC, `Date` did actually adopt `Strideable` briefly in some early betas (to support Combine functionality) but it was dropped because at the moment, retroactive (in time) conformances are an ABI-breaking change in Swift. There isn't yet support for indicating that a _conformance_ to a protocol was introduced in a specific OS release, but IIRC that's planned too.

Comment: We no longer have access to older Xcode beta release notes but I believe this was a brief consequence of the change: https://forums.swift.org/t/foundation-date-conforming-to-strideable-ios-13/33221

Comment: That explains a lot, but does that mean that there's any functional difference between the two methods, or that likely `advanced(by:)` is probably calling `addingTimeInterval(_:)` behind the scenes? I'd guess that I should probably use `addingTimeInterval(_:)` in just about every situation. Thoughts?

Comment: They're both actually implemented using `+`. Which you use is really a matter of taste. Personally I would always use `addingTimeInterval` because it's the traditional name, and IMO both `date.advanced(by: 4)` and `date + 4` are horrible syntax. What is "4" here? Seconds? Milliseconds? Nanoseconds? If I weren't deeply experienced in Cocoa, I would expect `date + 4` to add 4 *days* (it says "date" right there!) TimeInterval is defined to *always* be seconds, so it's clear when it says "addingTimeInterval." Everything else IMO is a source of very common mistakes. But others may disagree.

Comment: Those are excellent points! Will definitely keep this in mind going forward. :)