# What is the difference between timeIntervalSince and distance on Date?

Tags: swift, date, distance

What is the difference between `timeIntervalSince(_:)` and `distance(to:)` on `Date`?

They seem to serve the same purpose.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779636-timeintervalsince

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/3329238-distance

(except their logical direction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeIntervalSince(_:)` is an old NSDate method bridged from Objective C Cocoa Foundation.

`distance(to:)` is purely a newer Swift method, part of the Date overlay. It expresses itself in a more Swifty way, consonant with things like the  `+` overload and other conveniences, and is basically just a natural consequence of the fact that a Date is configured to be Strideable.

Comment: It has a Stride and the necessary methods, and this is one of those.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66321489/2303865

Comment: Yeah, weird eh.